# Javascript: why do a get aTypeError: xxxx is not a function using exports/require upon compilation

Tags: javascript, import, export

I export a function using :

**sendSmtpMessage.js**

```
'use strict';
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

exports.sendSmtpMessage = function(keys, mailOptions) {
  ...
  return true;
};
```

Then I import and use it in my index.js file :

index.js

```
const sendSmtpMessage = require("./sendSmtpMessage.js");
...
sendSmtpMessage(keys,mailOptions); // <=== error
```

I get an error compiling

```
TypeError: sendSmtpMessage is not a function
```

Comment: Just like the error says, sendSmtpMessage is not a function, it's a constant, therefore you can't treat it like a function by passing parameters to it.

Comment: @Difster Not true at all, `const` can indeed refer to functions without problems, just like you can use `let someFn = arg => 'returnValue'`

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Interesting. I've never tried to use it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing it as if it was the *default* export - import it as a named import instead (just like destructuring an object):

```
const { sendSmtpMessage } = require("./sendSmtpMessage.js");
```

Or, import it as you were doing before, but assign to `module.exports` instead of assigning to a property of `exports`:

```
module.exports = function(keys, mailOptions) {
  ...
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Got it... updated my code , it works! I'll vote for it